# comments in oracle script

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm pretty new to oracle syntax and I have been reading a bit but I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem.

So I have a sql file that contains multiple inserts into a database it works fine and does the insert but I keep getting ora-00001 messages. But it still does the insertion of the tuple into the table so I go back and remove out tuple by tuple to see what I am doing wrong.

And I find out that the comments are the things causing the error.

So if I have something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    T   varchar(10),
    primary key(T)
);

INSERT INTO TEST(T)
VALUES ('TEST1');
/*COMMENT*/
INSERT INTO TEST(T)
VALUES ('TEST2');
```

Why is this? If I remove the comment it doesn't throw me the warning is this something to do with setting or am I commenting...wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing comments with /* */ is done more in PL/SQL code. For a SQL script just prefix with --

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    T   varchar(10),
    primary key(T)
);

INSERT INTO TEST(T)
VALUES ('TEST1');
-- COMMENT
INSERT INTO TEST(T)
VALUES ('TEST2');
```

Comment: Ah okay I was wondering if my comment symbol was wrong thankyou